# Getting values from list

Tags: python

I got problem to get values from list.

I got opad1.txt file which looks like this:

```
4.6   2.3   1.9   0.4   0.2   6.8   0.4   0.0   0.1   5.5
0.0   0.4   3.5   0.3   2.3   0.1   0.0   0.0   4.0   1.5
1.5   0.7   0.7   4.9   4.2   1.3   2.7   3.9   6.5   1.2
0.2
```

I'm using code to read this file and convert each line to list

```
with open('opad1.txt') as f:
    opady = f.readlines()

dekada = [i.split() for i in opady]
```

And now i got problem to separate each value from list dekada.
When i use:

```
print(dekada[0])
```

The return is:

```
['4.6', '2.3', '1.9', '0.4', '0.2', '6.8', '0.4', '0.0', '0.1', '5.5']
```

My question is how to reach first element only '4.6' ?

Comment: first index so `print(dekada[0][0])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to have the content of your text file in a flat manner, you can do something like this:

```
with open('opad1.txt') as f:
    opady = f.readlines()

dekada = str.join(" ", opady).split()
print(dekada[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comment suggests, use another level to retrieve just a single item, as the first level just equals a whole list (I added the 'r' as well, for read-mode):

```
with open('opad1.txt', 'r') as f:
    opady = f.readlines()

dekada = [i.split() for i in opady]

print(dekada[0][0])
```

Outputs:

```
4.6
```

Answer (score 1):

`opady` is a list of your lines.  The `split` method for strings itself returns a list.  Therefore, `dekada` is a list of lists.  If you want a flattened list of just the strings, a "double" list comprehension is the way to go:

```
dekada = [x for x in i.split() for i in opady]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("opad1.txt") as f:
    opady = f.readlines()

dekada = [i.split() for i in opady]
print(dekada[0][0])
```

> Output

`4.6`

Answer (score 1):

You can use *f.read()* instead of *f.readlines()* and split it.

```
with open('opad1.txt') as f:
   opady = f.read().split()

dekada = [i for i in opady]
print(dekada[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.read` method to read all lines, so

```
with open('opad1.txt') as f:
    dekada = f.read().split()
```

and then,

```
print(dekada[0])
```

will print

```
>>> 4.6
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could put together all of the lines in a single list:

```
result=[]
for i in dekada:
 result.extend(i)
```

Then you can look for certain values using a for loop...

```
output=None
keyword=input("Introduce keyword: ")
for j in range(len(result)):
 if result[j]==keyword:
  output=j
  break
print(f"Your keyword is located in result[{output}].")
if output!=None:
 print(result[output])
```